# The difference between -mkl and -lm under intel compiler

Tags: c, intel-mkl

When I link library during my code compilation (intel compiler), if I use

`mpicc -lm -lmpi ...`, I have a warning says:

`icc: warning #10315: specifying -lm before files may supersede the Intel(R) math library and affect performance`

Therefore I use intel's math library `mkl`, i.e. `mpicc -mkl -lmpi ...`. I'm curious what's the difference between `-mkl` and `-lm`? If I just delete `-lm` without liking any math library, it also works. Why?

Comment: `-lm` specifies the generic math library, used for multiple similar systems. From what I understand, `-mkl` uses an optimized library specifically for Intel processors. For example: code compiled with `-lm` may work with `amd64` architecture, while code compiled with `-mkl` may not.

Comment: Using intel compiler, if I omit linking the math library, i.e. no `-mkl` and `-lm`, it can also pass the compilation. Does that mean intel can automatically link the basic math library?

Comment: the warning message is saying that there is no unresolved symbols to be resolved.   This is because the linker processes the parameter in the order given.  Suggest the -l parameter be moved to after any object file parameters

Comment: if it also successfully links with out specifying a 'math' library. That is a very good indication that there are none of the 'math' library functions being called in the source code.  However, you have not posted the source code, so we don't really know